# How to reload my UIViewController on click of some buttons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm developing an iPhone app, i have a `UIViewController` class where some coverflow animations are there and according to design i have some 5 buttons on top of my view each button have an `IBAction` method on clicking a button i need to display different set of coverflow with different data and the count of coverflow also changes from 1 button action to another. My problem is how can i refresh my page(reload) on click of these buttons, as i know calling explicitly `viewDidLoad` is a very bad idea, so how can i accomplish this? Any help is appreciated in advance thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to get a view to re-draw itself is to call [UIView setNeedsDisplay] or by using [UIView setNeedsDisplayInRect].  This method tells the view that it needs to re-draw itself and it's subviews.  However you shouldn't always have to call this.  There are other methods that can cause views to redraw themselves.  For instance if you add or remove a view to the view hierarchy using [UIView addSubview:] or [UIView removeFromSuperview].

These methods cause the system to call your view's drawInRect: method (assuming you overrode it with custom drawing code).  If you did not override this method for custom drawing then it should cause your subviews to receive the same message so that they can get a chance to redraw.

Additional information here.  Specifically read the section labeled "The View Drawing Cycle".

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to reload the page?, if it is because you are changing your view and you want it to be redrawn, you can call:

```
setNeedsDisplay();
```

But that is often not needed, as whenever a views bounds change that is called automatically for you.

Comment: awesome one helped lot

Comment: Once a boolean value is changed. I need to disable/enable a button. Would calling `setNeedsDisplay ` after the boolean getting changed enough? My view reads used the boolean property to decide. Needless to say I'm doing this, but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

If there's too much other stuff rather than refreshing/reloading the part of your interest in your viewDidLoad method, you can extract the refreshing part into a private method, say methodA. Every time you click your button, you call that methodA. However I think methodA still need call setNeedsDisplay or re-draw the the part of your interest. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your point is to refresh "UIViewController", then:

```
[self viewDidLoad];
```

Source: [How to refresh UIViewController programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225397/how-to-refresh-uiviewcontroller-programmatically)

Answer (score -2):

```
To Refresh your UIViewController, When Clicking the button >>

Add the below code into your UIButton method,

-(IBAction)button:(id)sender{
    [self viewDidLoad];
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
}

Now Build and Run Your Code.
```

Comment: Those are life cycle methods that shouldn't be called by your own code.

Comment: then how could you refresh the view controller? please explain @nobre

Comment: It depends on the context. The OP mention some custom coverflow implementation that probably uses a system of delegate/datasource to provide the content, so the best would be to use its own invalidation mechanism such as reloadData. In general though, you should extract the code you use in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear that builds the UI to another method, and call that one instead when needed. Remember that custom constraints cannot be added again. You can removeFromSuperview the element and add it again.

Comment: you should never call life cycle methods explicitly

Answer (score -11):

Use function viewWillAppear().This function is called everytime the view is called.

Comment: ViewWillAppear is executed on load of the View, it is not initiating the reload/refresh. Use [self.view setNeedsDisplay];