# UITableView reloadData not working when viewcontroller is loaded a 2nd time

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have a UITableView with custom cell displaying a list of files that can be downloaded. The cell displays the filename and download status. Everything working fine except one scenario :

1. The user downloads a file and navigates back to the home screen while file download in progress...
2. He comes back to the previous screen. File download still in progress.
3. File download complete. I am using tableview.reloadData() at this point to refresh the download status to "Download Complete" but reloadData() not working in this scenario. The cell label still shows "Download in progress".

***Scrolling the tableview to get the cell out of screen and back refreshes the cell correctly. Anyway to do this programmatically?"***

Otherwise, in normal case where user doesn't change screen, reloadData() is working fine.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

I have used alamofire download with progress in the function below which is inside my UIViewController.

```
func DownloadFile(fileurl: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath, itemPath: String, itemName: String, itemPos: String, ItemSelected:Bool) {

      let cell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! myCustomCell

      let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)


        Alamofire.download(.GET, fileurl, destination: destination)


       .progress {bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in


            // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
            // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead) / \(totalBytesExpectedToRead)")


                let progress = Int((Double(totalBytesRead)/Double(totalBytesExpectedToRead)) * 100)


                cell.lblMoreRuqyaFileInfo.text = "Downloading file...(\(progress)%)"


            }
        }
         .response { _, _, _, error in

           if let error = error {
                print("\(error)")
                cell.lblMoreRuqyaFileInfo.text = "Failed to download file. Please try again."
            } else {


            cell.lblMoreRuqyaFileInfo.text = "File Downloaded sucessfully"

          //reloadData() not working from here
            self.myTableView.reloadData()

            }

    }

}
```

The above func is being called in the tableview's editActionsForRowAtIndexPath  below.

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

```
    if myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) == nil {
        let action = UITableViewRowAction()
          return [action]

    }

    let cell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! myCustomCell

    let fileurl = cell.textLabel!.text
    let ruqyainfo = cell.lblMoreRuqyaFileInfo.text

    let sItemPath = cell.lblCompiledRuqya.text! + "->" + cell.textLabel!.text! + "->\(indexPath.section)->\(indexPath.row)"
    let sItemName = cell.lblCompiledRuqya.text!
    let sItemPos = "->\(indexPath.section)->\(indexPath.row)"
    var bItemSelected:Bool = false
    if myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark {
        bItemSelected = true
    } else {

        bItemSelected = false
    }

     //check if file already downloaded,return empty action, else show Download button
    if ruqyainfo?.containsString("Download") == false {
        let action = UITableViewRowAction()
         return [action]

    }


    let line = AppDelegate.dictCompiledRuqya.mutableArrayValueForKey(AppDelegate.dictCompiledRuqya.allKeys[indexPath.section] as! String)

    let name = line[indexPath.row].componentsSeparatedByString("#")

    let DownloadAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Download\n(\(name[3]))") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath) -> Void in

            self.myTableView.editing = false

            AppDelegate.arrDownloadInProgressItem.append(name[0])

            self.DownloadFile(fileurl!, indexPath: indexPath, itemPath: sItemPath, itemName: sItemName,itemPos: sItemPos, ItemSelected: bItemSelected)

        }

    DownloadAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    return [DownloadAction]
}
```

Comment: Show this part of your code please

Comment: You have to call the reload method in the download complete method

Comment: try redrawing viewcontroller, (having reload data in viewdidappear as well) .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225397/how-to-refresh-uiviewcontroller-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```
//Objective C
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       [self.yourTableView reloadData];
    }

//Swift
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Yes, this won't work as the download is still in progress while the screen is already loaded a 2nd time. reloadData() inside viewWillAppear won't help in this case.

Comment: Could you add some details regarding your code and it how addresses the problem(s) in the question? Code only answers are not very useful, especially for future readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks,

Comment: It's pretty obvious, he refreshes every time the view is visible again, therefore it should always be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

you can use delegates so that the download controller can tell the first controller that the download is complete, and that it should redraw the tableView - or at least the indexPath that has just completed.

set up the download controller like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    let destinationController : DownloadController = segue.destinationViewController as! DownloadController
    destinationController.delegate = self

    destinationController.indexRowToRefresh = currentlySelectedIndexRow        
}
```

and then in the download completion closure, add something like this

```
   delegate.refreshTableRow(indexRowToRefresh)
```

and in your first controller, implement the delegate method to refresh this row (or the whole table)

```
func refreshTableRow(indexRowToRefresh : Int)
{
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexRowToRefresh, inSection: 0)
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @John Make sure your TableView datasource is reflected with file upload status permanently.
I think, when you complete file uploading you change status in tableview datasource

1. First scenario as you are switching to second view controller, and coming back to previous view, it might be reinitializing your datasource. Data source might wasn't permanently reflected.
2. In normal scenario, as you are on same view controller(not switching to other). Tableview datasource might be not reinitialized holding updated file upload status.

I suggest to save user file download status saved at some persistant storage or on web server. That doesn't leads to inconsistency in data.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a thread related issue (aka you're coming back from the download thread, not on the UI thread, hence the data is refreshed but not displayed).

Try using this on `self`and pass it a selector that refreshes your tableview.

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:
```

Comment: I have tried that.. but it doesnt work too!
                self.myTableView.performSelectorOnMainThread(Selector("reloadData"), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)

Answer (score 0):

You used :

```
let cell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! myCustomCell
```

and set text for `lblMoreRuqyaFileInfo` :

```
cell.lblMoreRuqyaFileInfo.text = "File Downloaded sucessfully"
```

so, you don't have to call `self.myTableView.reloadData()`
Try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        cell.lblMoreRuqyaFileInfo.text = "File Downloaded sucessfully"
    }
```

p/s and where did you call function`DownloadFile` , show it, plz!

Comment: I have already tried that...but its not working too. This issue is happening only if while the file is downloading, the user navigates to the home screen...and comes back to the tableview screen. The status label then shows "Download in progress...". Then, while still on the same screen, the download is complete. Thats when reloadData() is called to change the label. I am calling Downloadfile function from within the editActionsForRowAtIndexPath tableview function.

Comment: I have pasted it above.