# Reload ViewController with button

Tags: ios, c

How can I reload my ViewController?

I'm making an iphone game and when it's "game over" you can press a button to replay. The action of this button should reload the view, but how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reload my UIViewController on click of some buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725215/how-to-reload-my-uiviewcontroller-on-click-of-some-buttons)

Comment: This didn't do the job for me.

Comment: Usually I think most developers would have a reset method.  If you wanted to have a kind of cheap work around, you could put Game Over in another view controller, and when replay is pressed, dismiss it.